# Finding Matching Values in Different Workbooks and Changing Part of the Row Based on a Third value

Tags: vba, excel

I have two worksheets in different workbooks.  Each sheet can have only a few lines to thousands of lines.  They never have the same number of lines.

In Column E of the Capital worksheet, I want to find any and all cells that contain ITS#### where #### are numeric characters.  When a cell is identified, I want to go to column A of that row and identify that value.  I then want to find the value I just identified (Column A) in column J of the Trans worksheet which is in a different workbook.  If a match is found, I want the value of column I in the Trans workbook to be changed to "Cost of Goods Sold/Expense.

I have searched the Internet for weeks and have tried many different solutions to similar problems, but have found nothing that works.  I believe I could figure it out if someone could get me past the indicated line.  I keep getting a

> Run-time error 1004 Method Range of object _worksheet failed.

The following code is one that I was working on, but I was just tying to get past the error so it doesn't even try to tackle the entire problem.

Thank you for any help you may provide.

```
Sub ITSTRANSCOM()
'
' ITSTRANSCOM Macro
'
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim i As Variant
Dim C As Variant
Dim Lrow As Variant
Dim Lastrow As Variant

Set ws1 = Worksheets("Capital")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("Trans")
Lrow = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "A:A").End(xlUp).Row
Lastrow = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "j:j").End(xlUp).Row

'Run-time error occurs on next row.
For Each i In ws1.Range("A:A", Lrow)
    For Each C In ws2.Range("J:J", Lastrow)
        If i.Cells.Value = C.Cells.Value Then
            If C.Cells.Value = "ITS####" Then
               i.Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
            End If
        End If
        Next C
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Dim I as Integer, C as Integer
Dim Tmp_Val as Variant
For I = 1 to LRow
    If Left(UCase(Ws1.Range(“E” & I).Value),3) = “ITS” then
        Tmp_Val = Ws1.Range(“A” & I).Value
        For C = 1 to LastRow
            If Ws2.Range(“J” & C).Value = Tmp_Val then
                Ws2.Range(“I” & C).Value = “Cost of Goods Sold/Expense”
                Exit For
            End if
        Next C
    End if
Next I
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  For some reason, my computer did not like your quote marks and I had to replace them before it would work.

Comment: @FloridaRick no problem. And that’s weird, but easily fixed I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution looks like it is on the way there...just try replacing the line:

```
If C.Cells.Value = "ITS####" Then
```

With the line:

```
If UCase(Left(C.Cells.Value,3)) = "ITS" Then
```

I think that will allow you to identify the cells you want, and you seem like you should be capable of developing the code to shift those values between your sheets (based on your other code).

Comment: Thank you, but I received the same error and at the same spot.  It doesn't seem to like the line which is three lines ABOVE the one you are having me change.

Comment: Oh sorry. Are you just trying to loop through all the rows? If so, try: For I = 1 to LRow and then use range variables in place of i and c inside the loop...Give me a bit of time, as I’m out atm...but I can post a better solution when I get home.

Comment: Nothing is visible to me after "If so, try:"  Yes, I do want to loop through all of the rows.  The ITS numbers can be anywhere in Column E and the other numbers can be anywhere in column J.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

`For Each i In ws1.Range("A:A", Lrow)`

to

`For Each i In ws1.Range("A1", "A" & Lrow)`

Same with `For Each C In ws2.Range("J:J", Lastrow)`:

`For Each C In ws2.Range("J1", "J" & Lastrow)`

Answer (score 0):

Looks simple. Perhaps I did not get your explanations right ?

```
Dim c As Range, r As Range
For Each c In ws1.Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues).Cells
    If c.Value Like "ITS[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]" Then
        Set r = ws2.Range("J:J").Find(c.Value)
        If Not r Is Nothing Then
            r.Offset(0, -1) = "Cost of Goods Sold/Expense"
        Else
            Debug.Print c.Value, " not found"
        End If
    End If
Next c
Debug.Print "Done"
```